# couchdb joins for 2 documents

Tags: join, couchdb

I am new to couchdb and I need to make a join and get results from 2 documents type.

I have `type="registeredEvent"` in one document and `type="user"` in another. The schema of both the type are as follows:

**registeredEvent**

```
{
   "_id": "316ff4844ce56...",
   "_rev": "2-5dcfb85eaea3f....",
   "eventid": "0620F01F-3B6B-DE07-860A-SF453FF5AELP11",
   "email": "amaya@gmail.com",
   "type": "registeredEvent"
}
```

**Users**

```
{
   "_id": "Profile_amaya@gmail.com",
   "_rev": "1-89768208cfb5650ee....",
   "name": "amaya",
   "email": "amaya@gmail.com",
   "dob": "91-07-14",
   "gender": "Female",
   "location": "canada",
   "facebook": "dghdfj",
   "twitter": "fgfghh",
   "type": "user"
}
```

I want to get data for populating a graph.

1. I have a list of eventid's and I want to get count of females in those events.
2. I also want to have the no of users in each of these events but are in the age group 17-28

I am using the following to fetch data

```
db.query('event/getGraphdata1...',{keys: [<array of eventid's>], include_docs: true })
```

Can anybody help me out. I have tried a number of things but of no success. I could not check if I am on the right track as all the things provided me with wrong data.

Comment: I have tried "linked documents" but unsuccessfuly :-(

Comment: I want to join the email field of the registeredEvent to the _id of the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data of gender, age using list like:

```
function(head, req) { 
       var row; var counts = {}; var male = female = age18 = 0;
       while(row = getRow()) {
         if(row.doc != null) { 
            if(row.doc.gender != null && row.doc.gender.toLowerCase() === 'male') 
                male++; 
            else 
                female++;
            if(row.doc.dob != null && Array.isArray(row.doc.dob)) { 
                var age = 0;
                var date1 = new Date(row.doc.dob[0], row.doc.dob[1], row.doc.dob[2]);
                var date2 = new Date();  var m = date1.getMonth(); 
                var years = date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear(); 
                date1.setFullYear(date1.getFullYear() + years); 
                if (date1.getMonth() != m) date1.setDate(0); 
                age = date1 > date2 ? --years : years; 

                if(age < 29) 
                    age18++;
            }
         }
     }
     counts['male'] = male;counts['female'] = female; counts['age18'] = age18; send(JSON.stringify({'counts' : counts}))
 }
```

You can extend this to support more age groups if needed...

Answer (score 1):

You can get one result set from these 2 document using following view:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'registeredEvent') {
     emit(doc.eventid, {_id:"Profile_" + doc.email}, doc.user);
   }
}
```

When requesting using HTTP API add include_docs=true

Comment: Thanks for your answer @wiz. This takes me one step ahead in getting the result as needed. But still the question is unanswered completely.

Is there any way I can apply a filter on the second document that is fetched? I have gender as "male" or "female". I want to get a count of all the males after the above join.