# How complex (Big-O notation) are CouchDB list views emulating JOIN?

Tags: join, couchdb

I'm thinking about using a Couchdb list view as described in the answer to [couchdb joins for 2 documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510788/couchdb-joins-for-2-documents)

Before I go down that path and invest even a single CPU cycle on benchmarking (good benchmarks are hard!), I'm just wondering what is the [Big-O time complexity](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) I should expect once the data starts growing?

Comment: CouchDB views are built incrementally, not on-demand. I don't think Big-O complexity really applies in this situation.